# Does 'coming from <a person>' necessarily refer to the speaker?

Tags: reference

If I were to say something like "That's false, coming from someone who has lived in China for 3 years", then does the 'someone' in the sentence necessarily refer to myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Coming from someone..." does not necessarily have to refer to the speaker (first person) Although, it is always singular. Consider:

*"I understand why that would seem valid,* ***coming from someone*** *with a mother like yours."* (Second person)

*"Fashion critiques are hard to take seriously,* ***coming from someone who dresses like Zelda."*** (Third person)